# Break nested loop

Tags: matlab

I have three nested loop in Matlab and in each loop, I have an "if" that check a flag. If it was OK, the the algorithm proceeds, otherwise, I want that the program should be terminated. Here is my codes, I think something is wrong!

```
[A] = finction (...,...,...)

for i = 1:100
for j = 1:100
for k = 1:30

some operation which its results is a flag

if flag==1 % its initial value is 0
break
end;
end;
end;
end;
```

Where is should put that break in order I break the rest of the computations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BREAK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html) terminates the execution of a loop, so if you have a nested loop, `break` will only quit the innermost loop, and the program will continue running.

If you want the entire function to be terminated, you need to use [RETURN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html). Please note that at the moment `return` is called, all the requested output arguments must be assigned to some value, otherwise the code will throw an error.